# Django - view of a users profile model once they are logged in

Tags: django

Im having problems with displaying the logged in users profile. I have created a profile app with some users details such as address.

```
def profile_view(request):
user_id = request.user.user_id
profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
context = {'profile': profile}
template = 'profiles/profile.html'  
return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Can you please paste the template code?

Comment: I'm not aware of a property called `user_id` that exists on the built-in Django `request.user` object. Unless the user is authenticated, `request.user` will be an anonymous user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this...

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context = {
        'profile': profile
    }
    template = 'profiles/profile.html'  
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!!